# Dismissing View controllers and then presenting them

Tags: ios

I have an application that has 3 view controllers.

The first one presents the second one and the second one then presents the third one. I then have a button that I want to bring me back to the first view controller. This button works. However, I try to present the 2nd view controller from the first and then the 3rd view controller from the 2nd again. Presenting the 2nd view controller works fine, but presenting the 3rd view controller doesn't work. I get the error:

Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

The first view controller is the main menu to the game, the second view controller is where the game occurs and the third view controller is the end result screen. Is there a better way to do it than my way?

Does anyone have a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are they modal segues?

Comment: Well I did not use storyboard for my application. I only used code for everything. I used the methods [self presentViewController:viewController animated:BOOL completion:^(void)completion]; and [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:BOOL completion:^(void)completion];.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a navigation controller. All you're doing now is pushing views in an infinite loop.

Here is a really good site to read with examples.

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/01/ios-navigation-view-controller-example.html

Comment: Will view controllers be deallocated from memory when a new view controller is added to the stack? I'm asking for performance reasons because since I'm making a game I need to make sure the current view controllers have the best performance possible.